# Import files to a grid window

Tags: guptateamdeveloper

I try to import .xls and .xml files into a Grid window, but with no luck.  I succeed with .csv and .txt

Set bok =SalGridDataExport( gridState, sPath,Format_EXCEL )

OR can you answer this:

Does anybody have used this function with a success using TD6.3 
For me it worked fine using 6.2 some week agao

Thanks

Solved

copied olexlsf.dll  to C:\Windows\SysWOW64 and run the 
"regsvr32.exe olexlsf.dll" from here